# How to share a cookie between two domains I control?

Tags: http, cookies

I want to share a cookie between two domains (and two backends) I control.

My flow is:

1. Frontend A makes a request to Backend A, hostend under a-backend.com
2. Backend A returns a `Set-Cookie` header with a cookie value with domain set to: `b-frontend.com` and `SameSite=None` and `Secure=True` properties. It also sends header `Location: b-frontend.com`.
3. I want the cookie to be set for the `b-backend.com` and browser user automatically redirected to `b-frontend.com` site.
4. Although the browser (Chrome) says in Network Tools that: "This attempt to set a cookie via a Set-Cookie header was blocked because its Domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url."

Am I missing something here, to make this flow working as expected?

The caniuse.com site says (https://caniuse.com/?search=samesite) it should be legit to support `SameSite=None` attribtue to share the cookie.

Anyone can tell what is wrong here?

[image: Browser Response]

[image: Browser Blocked]

Answer (score 1):

> How to share a cookie between two domains I control?

You can't.

> The caniuse.com site says it should be legit to support SameSite=None attribtue to share the cookie.

You've misunderstood what `SameSite` does.

Scenario:

1. A user visits *example.net* which sets a cookie.
2. They they visit *example.com* which includes `<img src="http://example.net/foo.png" alt="...">`

The SameSite attribute determines if the cookie will be sent or not. (Subject to other restrictions such as [Firefox's Total Cookie Protection](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2021/02/23/total-cookie-protection/).).

---

If you want to set a cookie for *example.net* then the `Set-Cookie` header must be placed in the response to a request to an *example.net* URL.

You might acheive this by redirecting the user from *example.com* to *example.net* (perhaps with a token (e.g. a JWT) to verify the request) and having the response set the cookie and redirect the user back to *example.com*.